# Getting week of the month. Week should start on Monday and end a Sunday

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, sql-date-functions

I need to add new business wee to my dim_date actually i have week of the month that is counting every 7 days of month as the table bellow.

| Date | Week of month | day_of_week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/04/2022 | 1 | Friday |
| 02/04/2022 | 1 | Saturday |
| 03/04/2022 | 1 | Sunday |
| 04/04/2022 | 1 | Monday |
| 05/04/2022 | 1 | Tuesday |
| 06/04/2022 | 1 | Wednesday |
| 07/04/2022 | 1 | Thursday |
| 08/04/2022 | 2 | Friday |
| 09/04/2022 | 2 | Saturday |
| 10/04/2022 | 2 | Sunday |

But for this business week column the week should start on Monday and end at Sunday, even if the first week is only one day(when a month starts at Sunday), but if the month starts on Friday, I should consider it as the first week of the month.

| Date | Week of month | day_of_week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/04/2022 | 1 | Friday |
| 02/04/2022 | 1 | Saturday |
| 03/04/2022 | 1 | Sunday |
| 04/04/2022 | 2 | Monday |
| 05/04/2022 | 2 | Tuesday |
| 06/04/2022 | 2 | Wednesday |
| 07/04/2022 | 2 | Thursday |
| 08/04/2022 | 2 | Friday |
| 09/04/2022 | 2 | Saturday |
| 10/04/2022 | 2 | Sunday |

Do you have any suggestion to calculate this?
Thank you

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

This query gets the number of the week from `2002-04-01` to `2002-04-19`. The week start from monday and finishes on sunday. You can see this example:

```
with sample_data as (
    SELECT date FROM UNNEST(generate_timestamp_array('2022-04-01', '2022-04-19', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as date
)

select
    date 
    , extract(week(MONDAY) from  date)-(extract(MONTh from  date)-1)*4 AS days_diff
    ,  FORMAT_DATE('%A', date)
from sample_data
```

You can see the result.

[image]

You need to use `EXTRACT` function.

Comment: @FernandoGomes if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: hi Raul it doesnpt weork when we have a yar change scenario.
this example:

`with sample_data as (
    SELECT date FROM UNNEST(generate_timestamp_array('2021-01-01', '2022-01-19', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as date
)

select
    date 
    , extract(week(MONDAY) from  date)-(extract(MONTh from  date)-1)*4 AS days_diff
    ,  FORMAT_DATE('%A', date)
from sample_data`

Comment: you could see in the comment the solution i figured out

Comment: @FernandoGomes As a new member of Stack Overflow, I recommend you take some time to review this process: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

i hope that this solution i figured out could help you in the future or we can discuss and imporve this solution:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT
                     date,
                     EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,
                     DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) AS FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH
                 FROM (SELECT date
                       FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2022-04-01', '2022-04-19', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS date))
SELECT
date,
FORMAT_DATE('%A', date) as day_name,
CASE
    WHEN CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM d.date) AS INT) = 0 AND d.WEEK_OF_YEAR IN (52, 53) THEN 1
    WHEN CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM d.FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH) AS INT) = 0 THEN EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM d.date) + 1
    ELSE (d.WEEK_OF_YEAR - CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM d.FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH) AS INT)) + 1
END AS BUSINESS_WEEK_OF_MONTH
FROM sample_data d;
```